# discord-ui Button Listener called twice

Tags: python, discord.py

I've an issue I can't fix.
Indeed, I'm trying to develop a discord bot, and when asking some questions by DM, the bot is publishing a message to a specific channel with a button, until there everything works fine.

But I'd try to catch the event on button click, I'm using [discord-ui v5](https://discord-ui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/listeners.html) with [discord.py v1.7](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) and Python 3.8.
I register my listener which is well called, this listener aims to DM the user who clicked on.
Unfortunately, the listener is called twice, the direct issue is user has twice the same message, that I wouldn't have.

Here my code :

main.py :

```
import discord
import locale
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_ui import UI, Button, Components, Listener
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
from src.workflows.main import MainWorkflow
from src.workflows.subscription import SubscriptionWorkflow
from src.listeners.awesome_listener import MyAwesomeListener

path = Path()
load_dotenv(path.resolve() / ".env")

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True


locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)
ui = UI(bot)
components = Components(bot)
workflow = MainWorkflow()

@bot.command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    ...

    signup_channel = bot.get_channel(signup_channel_id)

""" EVERYTHING WORKS FINE UNTIL THERE """
    
    sent_message = await signup_channel.send(message_for_run, components=[
            Button(label="JLabel", color="green", custom_id="my_id"),
        ], listener=MyAwesomeListener(workflow))


bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN"))
```

awesome_listener.py :

```
from discord_ui import Listener
from src.workflows.subscription import SubscriptionWorkflow

class NewRunListener(Listener):
    def __init__(self, workflow) -> None:
        self.subscription_workflow = SubscriptionWorkflow()
        self.workflow = workflow

    @Listener.button("my_id")
    async def my_func(self, ctx):

        """ THE CODE BELOW IS EXECUTED TWICE """

        cheers = await self.subscription_workflow.cheers(ctx, self.workflow.run)
        await ctx.author.send(cheers)
```

I'm pretty sure it's an idiot mistake but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to know who clicked a button. In that case you can use: interaction = await self.bot.wait_for("button_click") and then it’s simple to grab the user using interaction.user

Comment: Thank you for answering, but actually, with the information of who clicked on the button, I need to fire other codes, in my example it's starting by DMing the user.
However, I'll give a try on your solution, even if I'd prefer working with listeners, your tip could really do the trick

Comment: Np happy to help!